# How to use the STS local boot services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-cloud-config

I Have installed local Boot CLI to my STS.

I can see below services which is provided by the Spring Tool Suite.

[image]

If i need to use these services for example configserver, where i need to give the Git Path and other configuration for the config-server.

Or if i write my own server is better? because i am learning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I final found the path where these service is installed

If install Spring Boot CLI in STS which is going to bring the jar's required for the CLI keep it in ~/.m2 maven repository.

The instance of the CLI is created in the STS workspace

```
<workspace>d/.metadata/.plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/installs/spring-boot-cli-<version>-bin/spring-<version>
```

which is same as running tomcat in eclipse where CATALINA_HOME will be created in the .plugins folder

Lets see the services which are shown on the dashboard by default.
These services are seperate or easy to use or ready made services which are commonly required. If you need a custom configuration based on your requirement we have keep the configuration in ~/.spring-cloud

For more information refer the [Git Source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/tree/master/spring-cloud-launcher)